# getting "Fatal Error" when any function is call by $cart in Prestashop 1.7

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7, prestashop-modules

I'm facing an issue, where I'm getting 'Fatal error' after adding product.

[image]

[image]

When I call any cart method, it leads to fatal error.

PS: 1.7.8.2
https://beta.claap.io/sendinblue/fatal-error-c-3YfMIiN6mG-AL7OcMGtoJMg

Comment: Copy-pasted code is preferred to images of code as it can be [searched for and tested out](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/12892553) and in addition [Users from certain countries can't view hosted images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/407369/12892553)

Answer (score 0):

As you can see from the error StackTrace , issue is caused by the "**sendinblue**" module, that executes some code in the "*actionCartSave*" hook.

Try disabling the module in first place to see if problem goes away,
then you need to check the module code (maybe there's an updated version?) to see where/when the fatal error arises.

Comment: Without "Sendinblue" module its working fine. But everything is working fine under 1.7.8.0 only for 1.7.8.0 and above, it's leds to an error.

Can you please help me to understand, how to get products in the cart, "actionCartSave" hook called.

Comment: You should investigate the code in actionCartSave hook of the module... I guess some fix has to be done to improve PS 1.7.8.2 compatibility.  Since sendinblue is a third party free module, you can also get in touch with developers and report them the issue.

Comment: I've check it as I've noticed that the $this->context->cart is null when product is added into the cart https://beta.claap.io/sendinblue/cart-is-null-c-3YfMIiN6mG-vI1bGz-C55V3? but why its happening?